# Look for one plugin which could send notification to any email when post publish

Tags: posts, email, notifications

when publish one post, I need to send notification to one special email, not admin, not author, not users, just one new email address.

Comment: If you are looking for plugin recommendations, then this is not the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

you can use following plugin for your post notification

[Better Notifications for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/)

[Download
wordpress publish post email notification](https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-post-email-notification/)